# Magento Payu error

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, payment-gateway, shopping-cart, payment

We are using `pay u` for our magento site, after installing `pay u` when user redirects to `pay u` site and click on browser back button without dong payment magento shows error like

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on a non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Observer.php on line 46
```

but order is already placed with status as 'processing' and after clicking on back button it goes to checkout page showing products in shopping cart.

That menas order is placed and shopping cart is not empty After resolving that issue of `observer.php` magento places order twice once with 'processing' status and one empty order.  Kindly help with this.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You get that error when you don't have all the data for the orders in the database. Check if you have any rows in `sales_flat_order_payment` that are linked to your order.

Answer (score 0):

PayU not work with it on a compilation. Turn it off, clear - and it should work.

```
php-f shell / compiler.php - disable
php-f shell / compiler.php - clear
php-f shell / compiler.php - state
```

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate with last answer, you need to go admin panel >>

system >> compilation and first comment your payu folder at

app/code/community/Payu

change it

app/code/community/--Payu

and access admin panel >> 
system >> compilation >> disable

after that remove comment from  payu folder and then run compiler from admin panel, but first uninstall your current payu and then install a new payu module.